# I am getting the "[Errno 2] No such file or directory" error code, even though I have the direct/absolute path.... Any Suggestions?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Code so far:

```
import pandas as pd import numpy as np

def getXDataMerged(): 
    a = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Applications/AIbot1.1/usbalanceannual.csv', delimiter 
    = ';') 
    b = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Applications/AIbot1.1/usincomeannual.csv', delimiter = 
    ';') 
    c = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Applications/AIbot1.1/uscashflowannual.csv', delimiter 
    = ';')

    print ('Income Statement CSV is: ', a.shape)
    print ('Balance Sheet CSV is: ', b.shape)
    print ('Cash Flow CSV is: ', c.shape)

    result = pd.merge(a,b, on=['Ticker', 'SimFinId', 'Currency', 'Fiscal Year', 
    'Report Date', 'Publish Date'])
    result = pd.merge(result, c, on=['Ticker', 'SimFinId', 'Currency', 'Fiscal 
    Year', 'Report Date', 'Publish Date'])

    result["Report Date"] = pd.to_datetime(result["Report Date"])
    result["Publish Date"] = pd.to_datetime(result["Publish Date"])
    print('merged X data matrix shape is: ', result.shape)

    return result
```

not quite sure what my issue is, my buddy has the exact same code (slightly differnt direct path because his folder is in a different place) and he has no issues.... Thanks In Advance!!!

edit: there is some more code below what I have shared, but it is not relevant to what I posted.

edit2: so I ran a code that would find the direct file path and print it out to me, and it said no such file or directory exists as a possible path... Why would this be?

Comment: If you wrap your strings in `pathlib.Path`, does that fix it?

Comment: The file must have a different name than you're expecting.  This will show the actual filenames in that directory: `import os; print(os.listdir(r'C:/Applications/AIbot1.1'))`

Comment: @BallpointBen not familiar with that, could I get an example please?

Comment: @JohnGordon It is giving me the same error code when I run that. How can that be when I am copy and pasting the direct file path into my code? I am on mac btw, and my .csv files are saved onto the Macintosh HD storage drive (iCloud drive wasnt working)

Comment: Macs don’t have drive letters

Comment: @BallpointBen how would that impact me?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is probably because of the forward slashes. Can you try it with the backslashes instead?

```
a = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Applications\AIbot1.1\usbalanceannual.csv', delimiter = ';') 
b = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Applications\AIbot1.1\usincomeannual.csv', delimiter = ';') 
c = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Applications\AIbot1.1\uscashflowannual.csv', delimiter = ';')
```

Comment: mmmm that didn't work.... I am copying and pasting the file path exactly from what my computer says it is....